# VBA works only once

Tags: excel, vba

Completely new to VBA here. I wrote this to try to display tabs when "yes" is selected in a cell and hide them when "no" is selected. When I open the workbook, it works one time, but then not again unless I close and reopen Excel.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If (interior_lighting) = "Yes" Then
Sheets("1- Interior Lighting & NLC").Visible = True
Sheets("1.1 High Perf. Guidelines").Visible = True
Sheets("1A- Space by Space").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("1- Interior Lighting & NLC").Visible = False
Sheets("1.1 High Perf. Guidelines").Visible = False
Sheets("1A- Space by Space").Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

When I first select Yes or No, the tabs hide or unhide properly. When I switch again from yes to no or no to yes, nothing happens. I expected the tabs to hide each time I select no and unhide each time I select yes.

Comment: What is `interior_lighting`? Is this the name of a cell you have modified? Why don't you use the `Target` input parameter?

Comment: yes, it's a name for cell C4 so that if I add or delete rows the code doesn't break. This is my first ever VBA, so I'm not sure how to use the Target input parameter. Are you able to expand on that? Thanks!

Comment: I do not know what interior_lighting is,So probably Excel does not either .Therefore it will treat it as "false" and it will run it all the time as a false.

Answer (score 1):

Your value `interior_lighting` is not calculated again when you modify the value of "C4". Try replacing your `IF`-clause by this:

```
If (Target.Row = 4 And Target.Column = 3 And Target.Value = "Yes") Then
```

Explanation:
`Target.Row = 4 And Target.Column = 3` : "C4"
`Target.Value` => that's how to check a modified value.

Have fun and welcome in the world of VBA.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Dominique's answer

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Do not repeat sheets object
    'It makes it easier to add or remove sheets
    Dim shtname As Variant
    shtname = Array( _
    "1- Interior Lighting & NLC", _
    "1.1 High Perf. Guidelines", _
    "1A- Space by Space")
    
    'Dominique's answer
    'Target Cells address and value
    If (Target.Row = 4 And Target.Column = 3 And Target.Value = "Yes") Then
        'Use loop Sheets
        For i = LBound(shtname) To UBound(shtname)
            Sheets(shtname(i)).Visible = True
        Next i
    Else
        For i = LBound(shtname) To UBound(shtname)
            Sheets(shtname(i)).Visible = False
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Change: Toggle Sheets' Visibility

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Me.Parent

    Dim tcell As Range: Set tcell = Me.Range("interior_lighting")
    If Intersect(tcell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim IsVisible As Long: ' or As Boolean
    IsVisible = StrComp(CStr(tcell.Value), "Yes", vbTextCompare) = 0
    
    wb.Sheets("1- Interior Lighting & NLC").Visible = IsVisible
    wb.Sheets("1.1 High Perf. Guidelines").Visible = IsVisible
    wb.Sheets("1A- Space by Space").Visible = IsVisible

End Sub
```